# ActiveMQ lost messages, how debug this?

Tags: php, debugging, activemq-classic

We use standalone ActiveMQ 5.13.2, php and stomp. Stomp work with ActiveMQ in synchronous mode (with receipt check).

Sometimes i see behavior that looks like lost messages.

We use own task management system, that provide working with different types of tasks.

What happens:

1) Task created, message sended in queue.

2) Message consumed from queue, task make api calls and etc, then new message sended in queue with time delay (need wait some time for remote service and then continue working).

And thats all, we got problem.

I expect that message sended on step 2 will be consumed from queue, but problem task still in state "waiting for consuming message", that looks like message in queue, waiting free consumer, or like time delay still not expired (but we have a lot of free consumers, queue empty and time delay expired).

For example, today this happens for ~50 tasks. Another tens of thousands tasks was completed correctly.

I sure that on step 2 message was sended correctly, because php-stomp library configured for confirming sending messages by receipt (we use this library: https://github.com/centraldesktop/php-stomp )

So my question: which way best for debugging this problem? For example, can i log in ActiveMQ for couple of days all information about messages sended in queue, sended in sheduler, moved in queue from sheduler and about consumed messages?

Or any another way exists?